# Choice of single-board computer for video output in embedded system

Tags: motherboard, linux, raspberry-pi, processor, video

I am developing a product that incorporates various sensors and actuators, and also a monitoring display (5" 800x480 TFT LCD HDMI).

Right now I have everything figured out with an Arduino handling all sensors/actuators and a Raspberry Pi Zero for WiFi and graphical output, but I need to think ahead for a potential mass production where raspberry pi zero is not available for bulk order...

GR8 C.H.I.P. Pro does not have good support for displays neither. The old C.H.I.P. would have been perfect but it has been discontinued.

Any suggestions ?